# TOR Icon to Display on Desktop or Activities Bar

Tags: tor

I was able to install TOR to a "folder" within Home. I wan the Luanch Browser icon on the Activities Bar and/or the Desktop. I did copy to the Desktop but it doesn't appear and I couldn't fine the Appearance icon under Settings. So.... 1) how do I get it on the Activities Bar
       2) how make my Desksop Icons show up

Thanks,
Anguis

Answer (score 1):

If you mean launcher by activities bar, Simply you can open TOR from terminal and then find its icon on launcher and right click and choose `lock to launcher`.